# ReactDom render performance , multi render element idea , ruby-vite build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, vite, react-dom

I want to understand what can be bring of usage 2 or more ReactDom renders on the index.js, is it performance issue , or not best practice to render application on 3 different elements ? I am used vite(https://vite-ruby.netlify.app/) , and index.js is entry point of it.

```
const renderDom = (element, component) =>
  ReactDom.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      {component}
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById(element)
  );

renderDom('test-app1-element', <Component1 />);
renderDom('test-app2-element', <Component2 />);

if (document.getElementById('react_section')) {
  renderDom('test-app3-element', <Component3 />);
}
```